# How do I mount an XFS partition via /etc/fstab and non-root users can r/w to it?

Tags: mount, fstab, xfs

I have 2 XFS partitions I want to mount via `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1        /media/data        xfs        defaults        0        2
/dev/sdc1        /media/backup      xfs        defaults        0        2
```

Both are mounted at boot but when I try to access it as a non-root user, I get

```
$ cd /media/data
-bash: cd: /media/data: Permission denied

$ ls /media/data
ls: cannot access /media/data/audio: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /media/data/documents: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /media/data/downloads: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /media/data/images: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /media/data/video: Permission denied
audio documents downloads images video
```

Note that from the `ls` command there is a `Permission denied` error but the last line shows the directory names although they are in red font. I have tried doing `sudo chmod 766 /media/data` and `sudo chmod 766 /media/backup` but I still get permission errors when trying to access said mount points as a non-root user.

I am using Fedora 20 and I am not sure if this has something to do with SELinux but in my previous setup with a partition of NTFS, I don't get these errors and the partition was accessible by non-root users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have currently resolved this by:

1. Creating a new group and add my user to the new group
2. `chgrp` the mounts `/media/data` and `/media/backup` to created group
3. `chmod 775` to both mounts

I can now access said mount points as my user and any user added to the new group I've created.

Answer (score 1):

766 doesn't allow the user to enter the directory because the "x" (execute) bit is not set.  Better:

```
sudo chmod 755 /media
sudo chmod 755 /media/data
sudo chmod 755 /media/backup
```

Comment: `chmod 755` does make the user enter the directory but doesn't allow writing. So I guess I'd have to go with `chmod 777` as it seems to work. Question is, are there any security implications by doing this?

Comment: Well, yes there are security implications...but the only alternative is to give each user their own directory.  As an aside, I don't like using `/media/` for manual (`/etc/fstab`) mounts because Gnome's automount thingy likes mounting things there.

Comment: If you're on a single user system then `chown` `/media/data` and `/media/backup` so that your user owns these directories.